# How to setup websocket SSL connect using cpprestsdk?

Tags: ssl, websocket

I tried to connect to a websocket server with SSL. But always failed on connection(...).
I am new to cpprestsdk, I can't find doc on how to set SSL information to websocket_client.

```
websocket_client_config config;
config.set_server_name("wss://host:port/v3/api");
websocket_client client(config);

auto fileStream = std::make_sharedconcurrency::streams::ostream();
pplx::task requestTask = fstream::open_ostream(U("results2.html"))
.then([&](ostream outFile)
{
*fileStream = outFile;
// Create http_client to send the request.
uri wsuri(U("wss://host:port/v3/api"));
client.connect(wsuri).wait();

     websocket_outgoing_message msg;
     msg.set_utf8_message(obj.serialize());
     client.send(msg).wait();
     printf("send success: %s\n", obj.serialize().c_str());
     return client.receive().get();
})
```

it throws "Error exception:set_fail_handler: 8: TLS handshake failed".

Answer (score 0):

Documentation for cpprestsdk can be found here 
[C++ REST SDK WebSocket client](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/c-rest-sdk-websocket-client/). Although this doesn't show all the necessary information related to cpprestsdk it will help you.

And also you can get an SSL test example [here](https://github.com/microsoft/cpprestsdk/blob/master/Release/tests/functional/websockets/client/authentication_tests.cpp). I show a simple websocket client implemented using SSL or wss:// scheme

```
 websocket_client client;
        std::string body_str("hello");

        try
        {
            client.connect(U("wss://echo.websocket.org/")).wait();
            auto receive_task = client.receive().then([body_str](websocket_incoming_message ret_msg) {
                VERIFY_ARE_EQUAL(ret_msg.length(), body_str.length());
                auto ret_str = ret_msg.extract_string().get();

                VERIFY_ARE_EQUAL(body_str.compare(ret_str), 0);
                VERIFY_ARE_EQUAL(ret_msg.message_type(), websocket_message_type::text_message);
            });

            websocket_outgoing_message msg;
            msg.set_utf8_message(body_str);
            client.send(msg).wait();

            receive_task.wait();
            client.close().wait();
        }
        catch (const websocket_exception& e)
        {
            if (is_timeout(e.what()))
            {
                // Since this test depends on an outside server sometimes it sporadically can fail due to timeouts
                // especially on our build machines.
                return;
            }
            throw;
        }
```

And further examples here to guide you get it successfully is found here 
https://github.com/microsoft/cpprestsdk/wiki/Web-Socket

Comment: Note that the websocket.org service is discontinued so copy and pasting the sample code will throw errors when trying to connect.